# How to control pc from android phone?

Tags: android

I do not know where should I start to look and I don't know if I can use RemoteControlClient library for this, if yes how to use it,

if anybody know about that please help me, thanks for your helps...

Comment: Are you building an app, what OS does your PC have, what program do you want to control? It would be best if you asked a specific question.

Comment: I think nothing much you need to do at phone side, just any tcp connection, send some command, the rest is up to PC side implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to control the pc desktop by a VNC app like androidVNC. With your android device connected to a network (as well as your PC), knowing your PC IP that should work.

Another useful app is ftpcafe to navigate  your PC files through your android device.

Comment: thanks a lot I like your answer , let me try it...